# Identification of read-only parameters in an uploaded revit model in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to identify read-only parameters in an uploaded revit model in the forge viewer?

I have already tried to retrieve the information, whether it's a read-only parameter or not, with the viewer api (getProperties(dbId, onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)).

Also in the SQL database, which was exported from the uploaded model, i could not find any information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The read-only info is stored in attribute `flags`, both in the sqlite database, and in the *.json.gz files used by the viewer (more info about those explained in this [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer)):

[image]

Here's what the individual bits in `flags` represent:

```js
{
    Hidden    : 1 << 0, /* Attribute will not be displayed in default GUI property views. */
    DontIndex : 1 << 1, /* Attribute will not be indexed by the search service. */
    DirectStorage : 1 << 2,  /* Attribute is not worth de-duplicating (e.g. vertex data or dbId reference) */
    ReadOnly : 1 << 3 /* Attribute is read-only (used when writing back to the design model, in e.g. Revit) */
}
```

Comment: for the parameter 'Volume', which is a read-only parameter in the uploaded model, the value 8 is stored in the attribute 'flag'. The value 8 can also be found in parameters that are not read-only.

Comment: Perhaps we're both referring to different "read only" settings/flags. If you have a specific Revit model, with a specific property that you believe has the read-only flag set incorrectly, please share the file with us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we will pass it on to the engineering team.